# Add hibernate to existing web application in netbeans?

Tags: hibernate, web-applications, netbeans, vs-web-application-project

I have created a web application in netbeans and it works fine. Now for the learning purpose I want to use hibernate for the database interaction. I can create a new project with hibernate in netbeans but I don't know how to add hibernate in my existing project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Netbeans version 7.3.1

```
right-click on "Source Packages" >> New >> Other... >> Hibernate >> Hibernate Configuration Wizard.
```