# Hibernate Framework option is not seen in Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: hibernate, netbeans-8, developer-tools

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 (on windows 7, 64bit). While I'm creating a new web application on it, for the "4. Frameworks" section I can't find the 'Hibernate' option here...

[image: Hibernate is not seen]

Before it was showing that option, like this:

[image: Hibernate is seen]

I can't figure out the problem and so I am looking for a solution (Reinstalling NetBeans may give a solution, but I want any other solution because many times I have seen this problem, so reinstalling can't be a solution).

**UPD.**
Here, Tools > Libraries:

[image]

Comment: Is Hibernate registered as a Library? (see "Tools -> Libraries")

Comment: I think, It is registered as a Library. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, finally I have got it!!!
No need to reinstall netbeans for activating "Hibernate" framework option. According to the accepted answer of "[Add hibernate to existing web application in netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447891/add-hibernate-to-existing-web-application-in-netbeans)", I just try this in an web application project:

```
right-click on "Source Packages" >> New >> Other... >> Hibernate >> Hibernate Configuration Wizard.
```

which automatically activates 'SE' in my netbeans, Which is responsible for the problem. After that I found the Hibernate framework as before.

Comment: I still dont have it here